GCP Data Proc cluster creation Warning
Hey guys I am new to cloud and GCP. Encountering this warning message while creating a data proc cluster using the GCP cli. I have the firewall rule set for Dataproc to function. Yet getting this error.
gcloud dataproc clusters create cluster-ef3c --region us-central1 --subnet subnet-db --no-address --master-machine-type n1-standard-2 --master-boot-disk-type pd-balanced --master-boot-disk-size 70 --num-workers 2 --worker-machine-type n2-standard-4 --worker-boot-disk-type pd-balanced --worker-boot-disk-size 70 --image-version 2.2-debian12 --project
Waiting on operation [projects//regions/us-central1/operations/578f0ad9-3eb2-3f01-b906-bf562a2cf6f0].
Waiting for cluster creation operation...
WARNING: The firewall rules for specified network or subnetwork would likely not permit sufficient communication in the network or subnetwork for Dataproc to function properly. See https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/network for information on required network setup for Dataproc.
I have added the firewall rule for dataproc as mentioned in the documentation. And also added the ingress and egress deny rule.
